# Change the values of _Session in another application

Tags: php, session

Is it possible to modify the values inside the super global array [_Session](http://www.php.net/session) in PhP? Assume that the _Session is writing to files.

The reason I ask this is because I have two application, the front end and the back end. The backend uses some variables inside the _Session object, and the front end must be able to modify those values so that it can communicate with the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two application are sharing a PHP session, then each can happily modify `$_SESSION`.

For this to happen you will need to make sure both applications are storing the sessions in the same place and either:

- Both are on the same domain and the
  cookie path has not been changed e.g. using `session_set_cookie_params()`.

or

- You know the sessionid of the 'back
  end' application and in your
  'front end' application call
  `session_id('back-end SessionId
  here')` before calling
  `session_start()`. The two
  applications should then have the
  same session. The front-end application would then lose any data it had already stored up to this point in its original session.

Either way, two applications communicating by sharing session data doesn't seem a great solution

Answer (score 1):

$_SESSION is just as modifiable as $_POST and $_GET, just know that writing to $_SESSION and then doing a header redirect does not work since the session values arent written.